# Using CodeIgniter, how do I pass multiple variables via a GET form?

Tags: codeigniter, get

I figured out how to pass one.. but how do I pass multiple GET variables from a FORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most repeated question of all time in CodeIgniter, second only to "How do I remove index.php".

[How can I use GET forms with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755772/how-can-i-use-get-forms-with-codeigniter)

Google is your friend.

Comment: or If it's CI, "Phil is your friend". hahaha

Answer (score 0):

sending data from get is really a hassle so i suggest u to use post data instead. its easy and safe.

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to make my "results" bookmarkable. Any ideas on how?