# converting from php $_GET variables to code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, superglobals

I am learning to use the CodeIgniter framework. I am coming form a world where get variables determined which body file to include in the index.php.

So with the MVC style coding I am unsure how to have a skeleton view which subsequent views are just the body of the page.

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to try and load multiple views based on the data being sent through the $_GET variable. The documentation for CodeIgniter explains how to do this:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

The skeleton parts of your site would always be loaded by the controller with the part that changes dependent on the $_GET data.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, GET variables(as in querystrings, eg. ?var1=alice&var2=bob) are not normally used for passing data, because they are disabled by default. Instead, URL segments (see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) or POST variables are used.

If it is necessary to use GET variables, thus enabling use of $_GET and/or $this->input->get(...), see this:

[How can I use GET forms with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755772/how-can-i-use-get-forms-with-codeigniter)

Edit: This may be useful in regards to loading a subv-iew within a main view:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Header_and_footer_and_menu_on_every_page/